# UIView do not react on Apple Pencil

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios9, xcode7, uitouch

In my app some of `UIView`s don't react on Apple Pencil. When I make touch by finger, all works fine. I supposed that this might be caused by adding new property `type` in iOS 9. And I tried to change the type of touches:

```
touch.type = UITouchTypeDirect;
```

But this is readonly property. Does exist any way to make equal touch by finger and touch by Apple Pencil?

**How do I make my app react on Apple Pencil?**

Comment: try UITouchTypeStylus.

Comment: Teja, thanks for your attention, but what do you mean? Try to do this: `touch.type = UITouchTypeStylus;` ? UITouch is a readonly object, so I can't do this. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: when your app recieve a touch event, did you try to see what is the touch type ?

Comment: when u say some of UIViews don't react on Apple Pencil, do some of views react to apple pencil ?

Comment: can you show ur touches began method ?

Answer (score 1):

`UITouch` class determines whether the touch is made by a stylus or by a finger, as stylus have a pinpoint touch and finger has a soft corner touch. You don't have to specify any setting for apple pencil.

In the `touches began` method,

you can differntiate the touches as:

```
   if(touch.type==UITouchTypeStylus){
               //perform stylus action
   }
```